# FAKE build task fails to generate Wix msi

Tags: f#, wix, wix3, build-script, f#-fake

Trying to understand why the WixHelper in the FAKE library isn't working in my build script. I keep getting the following error.

> Error: System.Exception: Start of process C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\bin\candle.exe failed. The system cannot find the file
>   specified    at
>   Fake.ProcessHelper.ExecProcessWithLambdas@76-16.Invoke(String message)
>   in C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\ProcessHelper.fs:line 76    at
>   Fake.ProcessHelper.ExecProcessWithLambdas(FSharpFunc`2
>   configProcessStartI nfoF, TimeSpan timeOut, Boolean silent,
>   FSharpFunc`2 errorF, FSharpFunc`2 messag eF) in
>   C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\ProcessHelper.fs:line 76    at
>   Fake.WiXHelper.Candle(WiXParams parameters, String wixScript) in
>   C:\code\f ake\src\app\FakeLib\WiXHelper.fs:line 791    at
>   Fake.WiXHelper.WiX(FSharpFunc`2 setParams, String outputFile, String
>   wixSc ript) in C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\WiXHelper.fs:line 849
>   at FSI_0001.Deploy.clo@65-5.Invoke(String file) in
>   C:\projects\main\deplo y.fsx:line 65    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.Iterate[T](FSharpFunc`2 action,
>   IEn umerable`1 source)    at FSI_0001.Deploy.clo@59-4.Invoke(Unit
>   _arg3) in C:\projects\main\deploy .fsx:line 64    at Fake.TargetHelper.runSingleTarget(TargetTemplate`1 target) in
>   C:\code\fake \src\app\FakeLib\TargetHelper.fs:line 483
>
> ---
>
> ### Build Time Report
>
> Target             Duration
>   ------             --------
>   Clean              00:00:00.0200214
>   BuildApp           00:00:01.1277956
>   ProcessTemplates   00:00:00.0527962
>   Total:             00:00:01.2397715
>   Status:            Failure
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------    1) System.Exception: Start of process C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX
>   Toolset v3.10\ bin\candle.exe failed. The system cannot find the file
>   specified    at
>   Fake.ProcessHelper.ExecProcessWithLambdas@76-16.Invoke(String message)
>   in C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\ProcessHelper.fs:line 76    at
>   Fake.ProcessHelper.ExecProcessWithLambdas(FSharpFunc`2
>   configProcessStartI nfoF, TimeSpan timeOut, Boolean silent,
>   FSharpFunc`2 errorF, FSharpFunc`2 messag eF) in
>   C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\ProcessHelper.fs:line 76    at
>   Fake.WiXHelper.Candle(WiXParams parameters, String wixScript) in
>   C:\code\f ake\src\app\FakeLib\WiXHelper.fs:line 791    at
>   Fake.WiXHelper.WiX(FSharpFunc`2 setParams, String outputFile, String
>   wixSc ript) in C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\WiXHelper.fs:line 849
>   at FSI_0001.Deploy.clo@65-5.Invoke(String file) in
>   C:\projects\main\deplo y.fsx:line 65    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.Iterate[T](FSharpFunc`2 action,
>   IEn umerable`1 source)    at FSI_0001.Deploy.clo@59-4.Invoke(Unit
>   _arg3) in C:\projects\main\deploy .fsx:line 64    at Fake.TargetHelper.runSingleTarget(TargetTemplate`1 target) in
>
> ### C:\code\fake \src\app\FakeLib\TargetHelper.fs:line 483

### Build Script

all the targets seem to process except the "Wix" target.

```
    Target "ProcessTemplates" (fun _ ->
  traceHeader "Process Wix Templates"

  let ALLFILES = fun _ -> true

  let dir_bin = directoryInfo (_dir_build_root @@ "bin")
  let dir_mobile = directoryInfo (_dir_files @@ "MobileInstall")

  let wix_directories =
    [dir_bin; dir_mobile]
    |> Seq.map (fun dir -> (wixDir ALLFILES true dir))
    |> Seq.reduce (+)

  trace <| sprintf ""

  let replacements = [
      "@product.name@", "Foobar App"
      "@product.company@", "Foobar Company"
      "@product.description@", "Foobar Description"
      "@product.version@",if not isLocalBuild then buildVersion else "0.1.0.0"
      "@product.content@", wix_directories
      "@product.application@",  wixComponentRefs dir_bin
      "@product.productcode@", "21654944-cf96-447f-890f-f7642e3128ec"]

  trace <| sprintf "%A" replacements

  !! ("./*.wxs")
    |> Copy _dir_temp

  !! (_dir_temp @@ "*.wxs")
    |> processTemplates replacements
)

Target "BuildApp" (fun () ->  
  traceHeader "BuildApp"

  ensureDirectory _dir_compile

  !! (_dir_source @@ "**/*.csproj")
    |> MSBuildRelease _dir_compile "Build"
    |> Log "Build-Output: "
)

Target "Wix" (fun _ ->
  traceHeader "Build"

  let wix_path = ProgramFilesX86  @@ "WiX Toolset v3.10" @@ "bin"

  !! (_dir_temp @@ "*.wxs")
    |> Seq.iter (fun file -> WiX (fun p -> { p with ToolDirectory = wix_path; AdditionalLightArgs = [" -ext WiXNetFxExtension";"-ext WixUIExtension.dll";"-ext WixUtilExtension.dll"; "-cultures:en-us"]}) (_dir_deploy @@ (changeExt "msi" (filename file))) file )
)
```

### WiX Template

```
 <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" UpgradeCode="@product.productcode@" Name="@product.name@" Version="@product.version@" Manufacturer="@product.company@" Language="1033">
    <Package InstallerVersion="400" Compressed="yes" InstallScope='perMachine' Comments="@product.version@" Description="@product.description@"/>
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="product.cab" EmbedCab="yes"/>

    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" />
    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK35"/>
    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45"/>
    <!-- Remove repair -->
    <Property Id="ARPNOREPAIR" Value="yes" Secure="yes" />

    <Upgrade Id='@product.productcode@'>
      <UpgradeVersion Minimum='@product.version@'
                      IncludeMinimum='no'
                      OnlyDetect='yes'
                      Property='NEWPRODUCTFOUND' />
      <UpgradeVersion Minimum='@product.version@'
                      IncludeMinimum='yes'
                      Maximum='@product.version@'
                      IncludeMaximum='yes'
                      Property='UPGRADEFOUND' />
    </Upgrade>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action='PreventDowngrading' After='FindRelatedProducts'>NEWPRODUCTFOUND</Custom>
      <RemoveExistingProducts After='InstallValidate' />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

    <InstallUISequence>
      <Custom Action='PreventDowngrading' After='FindRelatedProducts'>NEWPRODUCTFOUND</Custom>
    </InstallUISequence>

    <CustomAction Id='PreventDowngrading' Error='Newer version already installed' />


    <Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 3.5. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK35]]>
    </Condition>
    <Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.5.2. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK45]]>
    </Condition>
    <Condition Message="This application requires at least Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR (VersionNT >= 601)]]>
    </Condition>

    <!-- Step 1: Define the directory structure -->
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="@product.name@">
          @product.content@
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

     <!-- Step 3: Tell WiX to install the files -->
    <Feature Id="Application" Title="Application" Description="The Application." Level="1">
      @product.application@
    </Feature>

    <UI Id="WixUI_InstallDir">
        <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
        <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="12" />
        <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

        <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />
        <Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="InstallDir" />

        <DialogRef Id="BrowseDlg" />
        <DialogRef Id="DiskCostDlg" />
        <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
        <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
        <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
        <DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" />
        <DialogRef Id="PrepareDlg" />
        <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
        <DialogRef Id="ResumeDlg" />
        <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />

        <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>

        <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg">1</Publish>

        <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>

        <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg">NOT Installed</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">Installed</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>

        <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg" Order="1">NOT Installed</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="2">Installed</Publish>

        <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>

        <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="ChangeButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>

    </UI>

    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
  </Product>
</Wix>
```

Seems to fail on this line:

```
!! (_dir_temp @@ "*.wxs")
        |> Seq.iter (fun file -> WiX (fun p -> { p with ToolDirectory = wix_path; AdditionalLightArgs = [" -ext WiXNetFxExtension";"-ext WixUIExtension.dll";"-ext WixUtilExtension.dll"; "-cultures:en-us"]}) (_dir_deploy @@ (changeExt "msi" (filename file))) file )
```

I've spent much of the day on this error and I am not sure what could be causing it.

Comment: Perhaps a naïve question - but does the tool path (`C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\bin\candle.exe`) exist on your system? This looks like something that needs to be explicitly installed...

Comment: Yes it does. I thought the same thing, sadly it wasn't that easy a fix.

Comment: did you try wrapping the path with double-quote character?